# nginx - redirect https://subdomain.example.com to https://example.com

Tags: nginx, redirect, https

I want to redirect `https://subdomain.example.com` to `https://example.com`. Here's what I'm trying:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name subdomain.example.com;
  return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;
  # ...
}
```

Requests going to `https://example.com` are fine, but https requests to the subdomain systematically time out. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the subdomain DNS record is right and using the same IP than the main domain ? If the main domain DNS record is right thus this means both server blocks are okay and this is not an nginx issue.

Comment: Thanks Xavier. The problem originated from DNS records indeed. It was a redirect pointing to the subdomain. Using a proper a-record solved the problem. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.